# EasyMock: call order on mocks created with @Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Is there any way to verify methods call order between mocks if they are created with @Mock annotation?

As described in [documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-order) it can be done with a mock control. But EasyMockRule does not expose control object. 
I have looked at [EasyMockSupport](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html) implementation, but have not found way to force it to use one control for all injected mocks. :(

```
public class Test extends EasyMockSupport {

 @Rule
 public EasyMockRule mocks = new EasyMockRule(this);

 @Mock
 private SomeClass first;

 @Mock
 private OtherClass second;

 @TestSubject
 private UnderTest subject = new UnderTest ();

 @Test
 public void test() {
   expect(first.call());
   expect(second.call());
   ....
   //Verify that calls were in order first.call(), second.call()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it is not possible. An enhancement could be to allow to set a control in the @Mock annotation. Can you please [file an issue](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues)?

In your case, you will have to create the mocks manually using the same IMocksControl like explained in the documentation.